Are individual reaction rates of reactant dependent on stoichiometry in non elementary reactions?

For the complex reaction with stoichiometry $\ce{A + 3B->2R + P}$ and with second order rate expression: $r_P=kC_AC_B$ are the reaction rates related by $r_A= r_B =r_R =r_P$? If the rates are not so related, then how are they related?

In non-elementary reactions the overall rate of reaction and order doesn't dependent on stoichiometry. But does the individual relationship between the rates depend on stoichiometry?

You cannot predict the individual rates from the overall reaction. It's not exactly that the rates "do not depend on stoichiometry," just that they cannot be determined only from the stoichiometry. However, you can relate the rate of change for one molecule to the rate of change of another using only stoichiometry. In this case you are given the rate of formation of P, and need to determine the rate of consumption of A and B and the rate of production of R. For example, for every 1 mol P you produce, you consume 3 mol B.

When $aA+bB+\cdots= rR+pP+\cdots$ rule is $\displaystyle r=-\frac{1}{a}\frac{dA}{dt}=-\frac{1}{b}\frac{dB}{dt}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{1}{p}\frac{dP}{dt}=k[A]^\alpha[B]^\beta\cdots$

Hmm. As it is not an elementary reaction, the equalities are not generally true, as there may be nonzero rates of contents of intermediate products. By other words, you try to match rates of different, explicitly unknown reactions, with no linkage between their rates.

@Poutnik, I have given the accepted definition of the rate, the stoichiometry tells us nothing about how the reaction proceeds, as an example consider $H_2+Br_2=2HBr$ which is anything but bimolecular with rate $\frac{1}{2} \frac{dHBr}{dt}$

@Poutnik I'm not disagreeing with you but I just realised that I think that we are using the wording 'complex reaction' in different ways. I took the reaction as written to be complex,  but  you are reading it as meaning the there are intermediates as yet unspecified . I've deleted my comment as I think its confusing things.

I am not sure if there is a not elementary reaction without intermediates. Just kinetic rates may differ a lot, from uranium-238 decay to lifetime of beryllium-8 in carbon-12 synthesis from 3 helium-4. I will purge my prior comments.
